# DesktopAcrylicController crashes in WinUI 3 app

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I am trying to use the acrylic brush in WinUI 3, I read the documentation and it says that I must create an auxiliary class `WindowsSystemDispatcherQueueHelper`.
I have followed the process but it throws an exception.

```
using Microsoft.UI.Composition.SystemBackdrops;
using Microsoft.UI.Composition;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI;
using WinRT;

namespace Alessia.Helpers
{
    static class BackdropService
    {
        public static bool TrySetAcrylicBackdrop(Window window)
        {
            if (DesktopAcrylicController.IsSupported())
            {
                m_sdqHelper ??= new();
                m_sdqHelper.EnsureWindowsSystemDispatcherQueueController();

                // Hooking up the policy object
                m_configurationSource ??= new();
                window.Activated += OnWindowActivated;
                window.Closed += OnWindowClosed;
                (window.Content as FrameworkElement).ActualThemeChanged += OnActualThemeChanged;

                // Initial configuration state.
                m_configurationSource.IsInputActive = true;
                SetConfigurationSourceTheme(window.Content as FrameworkElement);

                m_acrylicController ??= new()
                {
                    TintColor = Colors.Red
                };

                // Enable the system backdrop.
                // Note: Be sure to have "using WinRT;" to support the Window.As<...>() call.
                m_acrylicController.AddSystemBackdropTarget(window.As<ICompositionSupportsSystemBackdrop>());
                m_acrylicController.SetSystemBackdropConfiguration(m_configurationSource);

                return true; // succeeded
            }

            return false; // Acrylic is not supported on this system
        }
    }
}
```

And the auxiliary class

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Alessia.Helpers
{
    sealed class WindowsSystemDispatcherQueueHelper
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct DispatcherQueueOptions
        {
            internal int dwSize;
            internal int threadType;
            internal int apartmentType;
        }

        [DllImport("CoreMessaging.dll")]
        private static extern int CreateDispatcherQueueController([In] DispatcherQueueOptions options, [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] ref object dispatcherQueueController);

        public void EnsureWindowsSystemDispatcherQueueController()
        {
            if (Windows.System.DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread() != null)
                // one already exists, so we'll just use it.
                return;

            if (m_dispatcherQueueController == null)
            {
                DispatcherQueueOptions options;
                options.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DispatcherQueueOptions));
                options.threadType = 2;    // DQTYPE_THREAD_CURRENT
                options.apartmentType = 2; // DQTAT_COM_STA

                _ = CreateDispatcherQueueController(options, ref m_dispatcherQueueController);
            }
        }

        object m_dispatcherQueueController = null;
    }
}
```

The exception is in the first class, in the line `m_acrylicController.AddSystemBackdropTarget(window.As<ICompositionSupportsSystemBackdrop>());`

[image]

Comment: I tried your code on a plain WinUI 3 app and worked on Win11 and Win10. Can you try it on plain WinUI 3 app?

Comment: Based on your code, there seems to be no issue. Could you please provide a sample to help us reproduce the issue? And you could referto the [offical sample](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/main/WinUIGallery/SamplePages/SampleSystemBackdropsWindow.xaml.cs)